# Can I set my MacBook Pro's resolution to a that of a 27" iMac and then screen share to that iMac?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, resolution, screen-sharing

The iMac is Thunderbolt and my MBP is not, so I can't use Target Display Mode, but I'd like to use the bigger screen.  Can I make my MBP a larger-than-native resolution?

Better yet, can I share a second, virtual screen at the iMac's resolution and use the built-in screen at its native resolution as a side monitor?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you could set the primary display to bigger than that of your iMac, however I know some programs (Off the top of my head 'air display') create a virtual second display. Air Display is an iOS app however...I'm not sure it would be able to handle a 2560x1440 resolution.

Something you could try is remote connecting to your MacBook Pro from your iMac. This could *possibly* allow you to make it a large resolution.